# Webcam js Error in Chrome: Could not access webcam

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webcam, webcam.js

I am using Webcam JS in one of my projects.

https://github.com/jhuckaby/webcamjs

version I was using: 1.0.0
Latest version available: 1.0.5

It was working fine in both Chrome and Firefox. But lately webcam error started showing only in CHROME. Firefox still works fine.

Error that I received in 1.0.0: `Webcam.JS Error: cannot access webcam.`

I upgraded the version and now the error I'm getting in chrome is

```
Webcam.js Error: Could not access webcam.
Permission Error: Only secure origins are allowed
```

https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/prefer-secure-origins-for-powerful-new-features

My website has a secure origin.

Can anyone tell me why I'm facing errors like that?

I believe there's no point in copy pasting webcam.js code.

Here's the code I use:

```
Webcam.set({
      width: 320,
     height: 240,
     dest_width: 320,
     dest_height: 240,
     image_format: 'jpeg',
     jpeg_quality: 90,
     force_flash: false
    });
    Webcam.attach( '#my_camera' );
```

Comment: This explains why. https://github.com/jhuckaby/webcamjs/issues/124

Comment: FYI you can also run into this error if your JS is in an iframe of different origin to the main doc.  Mic, webcams etc also have cross domain security policies.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Chrome 47 requires that the site be HTTPS in order for user media / webcam to work! This is a brand new requirement that I didn't see coming...

Chromium Docs on the topic:
https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/prefer-secure-origins-for-powerful-new-features

This means I'll have to buy a SSL cert. The library should work fine in Chrome 47, as long as you are using it on 127.0.0.1, or over HTTPS.

[Issue Discussion](https://github.com/jhuckaby/webcamjs/issues/124)

[Solution](https://github.com/jhuckaby/webcamjs/releases/tag/v1.0.6)

Comment: I have Chrome version 54.0.2840.99 m and my site is not https. webcamjs loads as html5, not flash.

Comment: here is an example and you can see a code in the source https://webdoors.ge/ka/webcam

Answer (score 5):

You can permitted a specific site or port:

To ignore Chrome’s secure origin policy, follow these steps.

- Navigate to `chrome://flags/#unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure` in Chrome.
- Find and enable the `Insecure origins treated as secure` section (see below).
- Add any addresses you want to ignore the secure origin policy for. Remember to include the port number too (if required).
- Save and restart Chrome.

[See here!](https://medium.com/@Carmichaelize/enabling-the-microphone-camera-in-chrome-for-local-unsecure-origins-9c90c3149339)

Comment: This works for me. As i need access webcam for our in house software. But i would not recommend for large scale clients. For large scale i would recommend to buy ssl certificate.

Comment: Worked for me also.  For our local network web app.

Answer (score 2):

If you can't provide a secure connection yet, all you can do is use the fallback to flash. Use the config code in that lib:

```
 Webcam.set({
        force_flash: true
 });
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Webcam.set({
    width: 500,
    height: 400,
    image_format: "jpeg",
    jpeg_quality: 90,
    force_flash: false,
    flip_horiz: true,
    fps: 45
});

Webcam.set("constraints", {
    optional: [{ minWidth: 600 }]
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I also got this error.

Solution:

Make sure that your website is secured. Access it via `https` protocol.

Example:

Use

```
https://example.azurewebsites.net/
```

Instead of

```
http://example.azurewebsites.net/
```

Answer (score 0):

There is another approach for this kind of issue which helped me during the development and might be helpful for others. The solution is to downgrade the version of Google Chrome to the 46-th.

Here are the basic steps:
- Turn off updates in Google Chrome

- Go to C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application or to the directory where your browser was installed.
- You will find 2 different files out there: chrome.exe and old_chrome.exe. Rename chrome.exe to any other name and then rename the old_chrome.exe to chrome.exe
- Launch Google Chrome

You can find more detailed instruction here: http://ipswitchft.force.com/kb/articles/FAQ/How-to-downgrade-to-an-Older-version-of-Chrome

Comment: This method is useful only during the development phase. What if the project is running live and clients are facing issues? We can't tell 'em to downgrade as it may be hard for 'em to digest these kinda things.

Comment: then you can shift the project to https