# Webcam.js Error: No supported webcam interface found

Tags: jquery, webcam, webcam-capture, webcam.js

I'm using [Webcam.js](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/webcamjs) in my Laravel Project for capturing image.

I have already come across from this thread ([Webcam js Error in Chrome: Could not access webcam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34081919/webcam-js-error-in-chrome-could-not-access-webcam))

I did same but still, I got this error:

`Webcam.js Error: No supported webcam interface found.`

Here, I'm providing my project [link](https://growwell.prestigeapartmentsltd.co.uk/student/imageandgeocapture) which is loading over HTTPs.

My code

```
            Webcam.set({
                width: 320,
                height: 240,
                image_format: 'jpeg',
                jpeg_quality: 90
            });
            Webcam.attach( '#my_camera' );
        }
```

If anyone has any solution please provide.
I will appreciate your response.

Answer (score 11):

When you are using Webcam make sure you have deployed the application in an SSL based server. Without SSL Webcam won't work.
I have no idea about the WebCamJs but this should internally call getUserMedia() which works only over HTTPS or localhost.
It will be great if you can provide more insight into the issue.

Comment: Thanks for commenting. The issue has been resolved. My site was loading with HTTPs but my asset URLs are loading with HTTP. So I need to load all asset URLs with HTTPs.

Comment: I am using my application in localhost. i am also facing same issue but not resolved

Comment: Try running something like valet to get ssl on localhost it'll definitely resolve your issue